# With Meteor, how to I run a singleton that updates periodically while clients are connected?

Tags: meteor

I'm just getting started with Meteor and I have a REST API hooked up with publish / subscribe that can periodically update per client. How do I run this behavior once globally and only refresh as long as a client is connected?

My first use case is periodically refreshing content while clients are active. My second use case is having some kind of global lock to make sure a task is only happening once at a time. I'm trying to use Meteor to make a deployment UI and I only want 1 deployment to happen at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

publish/subscribe will work automatically only when clients are connected. However, do not put any functionality that you want to control amount of execution times in publish or subscribe functions. They might run arbitrary amount of times.

If you want some command to be executed by any client use `Meteor.methodss` on server side, and call it explicitly with `Meteor.call` from client template event.

To make sure that only one deployment happens at any given time, simplest way would be to create another collection, called for example, `CurrentDeployments`.And any time deployment script function in `Meteor.methods` is executed, check with CurrentDeployments.findOne if there are ongoing deployment or not, and only call new one if none is running.

As a side bonus, subscribe to `CurrentDeployments` in client, to disable 'deploy' button in case one is already running.

Comment: I ended up having a global counter that increments in `Meteor.publish` then decrements in `onStop`. Then I have an interval that's started up if one isn't running during `Meteor.publish`. During `onStop`, if the global counter is 0, I run `Meteor.clear`.